# Spark simple query to Ceph cluster - Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, networking, pyspark, ceph

I feel I'm missing something trivial here, please help.

Solution is based on these articles:

- Theory: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/why-spark-ceph-part-1-3
- Implementation: https://radanalytics.io/examples/ceph-source-example

## Setup

I have set up a CEPH cluster on a remote server (server A) and copied over some sqlite3 files. I have also set up a Standalone Spark cluster on an another remote server (server B).

Due to company security policies (firewall etc.), I'm unable to run Spark jobs from my local machine directly, so I had to setup a remote development environment on a linux server (lets call it server C).

So I am able to run code from my local laptop using my IDE, where the code automatically syncs and executes on server C and sends the job to the Spark cluster (server B) which is supposed to query the CEPH cluster on server A.

## Problem

I can't seem to query a simple .txt file on the Ceph cluster due to simple connection errors.
If I try to do the same with boto3, I can query Ceph without any problems, but with Spark it doesn't work.

## Code Snippets

This is the simple boto3 example which works:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  endpoint_url='https://ceph-host.com',
                  aws_access_key_id='my_key',
                  aws_secret_access_key='my_access_key')

# list objects in bucket
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
objects = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']

# print object names
for obj in objects:
    print(obj['Key'])
```

While trying to do the same with Spark:

```
import pyspark
import os


# Ceph authentication
access_key = 'my_key'
secret_key = 'my_secret_key' 
ceph_host = 'https://ceph-host.com'  # Add your Ceph host here
ceph_port = 6800


# Creating a PySpark session
cwd = os.getcwd()

conf = pyspark.SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("1_main") \
    .setMaster("spark://master-host.com:port") \
    .set("spark.jars", "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', "{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd, cwd)) \
    .set('spark.executor.extraClassPath',"{}/sqlite-jdbc-3.41.0.0.jar, {}/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar, {}/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.1026.jar".format(cwd, cwd,cwd))

spark = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)


# Adding the Ceph auth to Spark session (I've got too many params as I've tried everything possible from the internet)
hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "{}:{}".format(ceph_host, ceph_port))
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
hadoopConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")

hadoopConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint.region", "default")
hadoopConf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.disableGetObjectMD5Validation", "true")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.attempts.maximum", "5")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout", "5000")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.timeout", "10000")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.signing-algorithm", "S3SignerType")


# Querying a simple .txt file
url = str('s3a://bucketname/text.rtf')

l1 = spark.textFile(url).collect()

for row in l1:
    print(str(row))
    break
```

## Full error log

When using different ports, I get different errors, for example:

**ceph_port = 6800**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on s3a://bucketname/text.rtf: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
```

**ceph_port = 443**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://bucketname/text.rtf: getFileStatus on s3a://bucketname/text.rtf: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: tx00000080ad2dcdd081322-00642f09fd-5f7a-default; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null:403 Forbidden
```

**ceph_port = 1**

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on s3a://bucketname/text.rtf: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to ceph-host.com:1 [ceph-host.com/host-ip-address] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was really simple:

- Put **http** instead of **https** in the Ceph host url
- Use port 8000

> ```
> ceph_host = 'http://ceph-host.com'  
> ceph_port = 8000
> ```

- Set the Spark config not to use ssl

> ```
> hadoopConf = spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "false")
> ```

Works like a charm!